# titanium focus event fire multiple times on ios

Tags: ios, focus, titanium, refresh, tableview

I am developing an ios app by titanium VGA 5.0.2. I wanna refresh tableview on a tab:

```
win.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
     alert('Got Focus');
     load_tableview();        });
```

I run this code on simulator iphone5s 9.1. But this is fire multiple times. The alert keeps appearing on the screen.

Comment: where do you register the above event listener? Possibly it should be registering multiple times.

Comment: Its because you are displaying `alert`. In titanium for iOS alert is also a window and each time you are dismissing the alert the `win` is getting focus. Try to change the `alert` to `Ti.API.info`, it will print `'Got Focus'` only single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid multiple times tableview load like below

```
Var isFocussed = false; // Global variable to the file.
win.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
 if(!isFocussed){
 load_tableview(); // will refresh only once
 isFocussed = true;
}
```